# Docker pull error: no space left on device

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

While doing a docker pull I get this error message

> Handler for POST /images/create returned error: ApplyLayer exit status
>   1 stdout:  stderr: write XXXX: no space left on device

I checked the disk space and the Inodes and I have enough of them. I tried anyway to free some additional space and inodes. Despite this the error falls always on the same file (which rules out a potential space problem).

The image to pull is ~12Gb

> Filesystem             Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on /dev/sda4
>   3,0M  295K  2,7M   10% /
>
> Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/sda4
>   47G   15G   30G  34% /

I tried exporting the image from another computer and importing it on the computer causing problems. However I get the same error of 'no space left on device'

I tried removing all images, even deleting completely /var/lib/docker, restarting the docker daemon, without any luck.

Running on MacBook 12.11 with ubuntu 14.02 installed.

> kernel:
>   3.18.0-031800-generic #201412071935 SMP Mon Dec 8 00:36:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

docker version

> Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

docker info

```
Containers: 2
Images: 85
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:4-920131-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 6.185 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 33.83 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 8.061 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.139 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: false
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.18.0-031800-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.58 GiB
Name: geb
ID: TTQN:73Y5:IU35:CK53:UELX:HPRQ:BKMM:ZNNM:O56G:6WL3:RZXE:NV4H
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Make sure you check the disk space and inodes for the virtual machine (i.e., in Virtualbox) that is running your docker instances, not your host machine (the Macbook).

Comment: There is no virtual machine, he's running linux on the macbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`devicemapper` has caused me innumerable problems across various different kernels and OSs. Issues [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3182).

Jerome Petazzo has some [broader recommendations](https://jpetazzo.github.io/assets/2015-03-03-not-so-deep-dive-into-docker-storage-drivers.html#63) - although  BTRFS also had/has ongoing [serious](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8765088) issues, that has got it (and DeviceMapper, and AUFS on Ubuntu 12.04) pulled from production in previous deployments.

My preference for storage drivers is `overlay`, which is available since kernel `3.18` (further opinions [expressed here](http://batmat.net/2015/08/26/docker-storage-driver-dont-use-devicemapper/)):

```
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
```

Update `/etc/default/docker` with ([more here](http://blog.thestateofme.com/2015/03/09/using-overlay-file-system-with-docker-on-ubuntu/)):

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-s overlay"
```

(ensure you only have one `DOCKER_OPTS` - that file doesn't support BASH syntax as one may expect)

**edit:** I seem to recall the devicemapper fix is to delete everything as you have done, and reboot.